# Nested dissection for singular matrices

Tags: algebraic-complexity

Let $F$ be a field. Define $S_G(F)$ be the set of matrices $A$ in $F^{n\times n}$, such that if we replace all non-zero elements in $A$ with $1$, then we obtain the adjacency matrix of $G$ (the diagonals can be arbitrary).

We are interested in solving $Ax=b$ for $A\in S_G(\mathbb{F}_2)$. (i.e. find a $x$ where the equation is true). $G$ is planar and has $n$ nodes.

I've always thought this is easy through nested dissection, so a $O(n^{3/2})$ algorithm always exists by [2]. A closer reading shows there is a requirement that $A$ has to be non-singular, as pointed out by [1].

Is there an algorithm that solves $Ax=b$ in $O(n^{3/2})$ time when $A$ can be singular?

Maybe I just missed some simple amendments to overcome this non-singular requirement. I rarely see people talking this in papers using nested dissection.

[1] *Alon, Noga; Yuster, Raphael*, [**Matrix sparsification and nested dissection over arbitrary fields**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2505989), J. ACM 60, No. 4, Article No. 25, 18 p. (2013). [ZBL1281.65074](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1281.65074).

[2] *Lipton, Richard J.; Rose, Donald J.; Tarjan, Robert Endre*, [**Generalized nested dissection**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0716027), SIAM J. Numer. Anal. 16, 346-358 (1979). [ZBL0435.65021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0435.65021).